# How do I map JSON parameters to Jersey parameters?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I've been struggling all day, trying to bind a very simple JSON request to a method using Jersey. I can't seem to find what's wrong, any help is very appreciated.

My JSON request is as simple as this:

```
{"user":"xyz","pwd":"123"}
```

My Jersey class looks like this:

```
@Path("/rest")
public class JerseyService {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("authenticate.svc")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Response authenticate(
            String user,
            String pwd) throws IOException {

        Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok();

        responseBuilder.entity(JsonSerializer.serialize(Status.SUCCESS));

        return responseBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

When I send the JSON request to the service as it is, the "user" parameter is set with the entire JSON request as a String (user = "{\"user\":\"xyz\",\"pwd\":\"123\"}"), while pwd remains null.

I've tried using @QueryParam, @FormParam among another annotations with both "user" and "pwd", but I can't find a way for Jersey to bind the JSON values to the Java parameters.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use low level JSONObject or create your own Class to accept the json parameter.
The following is the example with JSONObject.

```

```
@Path("/rest")
public class JerseyService {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("authenticate.svc")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Response authenticate(final JSONObject login) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(login.getString("user"));
        System.out.println(login.getString("pwd"));
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok();

        responseBuilder.entity(JsonSerializer.serialize(Status.SUCCESS));

        return responseBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

```

Comment: That solved! Just had to add the jersey-json dependency to import JSONObject. Thanks!